# .isDirty is true after submitting and reloading InertiaJS page

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have a simple form with a "Save" button that shows up if the user has updated any of the checkboxes.

The form sends a **POST** request to a ***store*** route in a controller that creates new records in the databases and redirects them to the ***index*** route.

When the page reloads, it doesn't seem to reset the Inertia form isDirty state from true to false even when I manually refresh the page.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $restaurantCategories = auth()->user()
        ->currentTeam->categories()
        ->with('category')->get();
    $allCategories = Category::all();
    $filters = $request->only('search');

    return Inertia::render('Restaurant/Categories/Index',
        [
            'restaurantCategories' => $restaurantCategories,
            'allCategories' => $allCategories, 'filters' => $filters
        ]);
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    foreach (auth()->user()->currentTeam->categories as $category) {
        $category->delete();
    }

    foreach ($request->checkedCategories as $category) {
        auth()->user()->currentTeam->categories()
            ->create(['category_id' => $category['id']]);
    }
    
    return redirect()->route('restaurant.categories.index');
}
```

**Vue**

```js
export default{
props: {
        filters: Object,
        restaurantCategories: Object,
        allCategories: Object,
    },
data: {
       updateForm: this.$inertia.form({
           checkedCategories: this.restaurantCategories.map(
               (resCat) => resCat.category
           ),
       }),
    }
}
methods:{    
    //THIS METHOD IS CALLED WHEN THE SAVE BUTTON IS CLICKED
    sendUpdate() {
            this.$inertia.post(
                this.route("restaurant.categories.store"),
                this.updateForm
            );
        },
    },
}
```

I've tried setting a key to the save button and updating the key on `sendUpdate` method, and calling `Inertia.reload()`